# Upgrading react: is it really this simple?

Tags: reactjs

I'm following [this page](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html) to upgrade React on our just-released react app, project started last November, react currently sitting at 16.0.

So naively, I do `npm install react react-dom` as suggested, and it bumps my React up to 16.14.0. So where is my React 18? Am I right to think I want the hottest, newest. What is the upgrade page not telling me?

Comment: `npm install <name>` will consult the `package.json` or `package-lock.json` file and install a version that fulfills the constraints listed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `latest` tag or giving directly the version that you want

```
npm install react@latest react-dom@latest
```

or

```
npm install react@^18.0.0 react-dom@^18.0.0
```

Comment: `latest` is not a command, it's a tag. I think npm adds the `latest` tag automatically to the latest version.

Comment: True latest is a tag, I edited. For npm part I do not know actually if It adds automatically or no @FelixKling